# Simple CSS Question

Tags: html, css

**Here's the CSS**

```
.box {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
.box-title {
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    background-image: url(/icons/bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.box-content-container {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

a:link {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000000;
}
a:active {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000000;
}
a:hover {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
text-decoration: underline;
color: #000000;
}
a:visited {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000000;
} 

a.tag18:link {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
a.tag18:hover {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a.tag18:visited {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
a.tag18:active {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

**And the HTML**

```
<table width="100%"  border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" class="box">
  <tr>
    <th class="box-title-header" scope="col">Categories </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="box-content-container">
        <div align="center">
        <a class="tag18" href="http://www.site.com">Category 1</a>    
        </div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Q. Why does the font size not appear as 18px high, as defined in the CSS?

**EDIT:**

**I'd like to create one CSS style for most hyperlinks. I believe this is achieved with a:link**

**For additional styles you can create .style1 ...**

**Question** 
Can a:link exist with a:style1? It seems a:link overrides the style.

**Answer** 
 a:link overrides any a.pseudo-class. For multiple styles use a:link, then additional hyperlink styles require  ' .classname a:link ' This can be achieved in HTML with [ span class = 'classname' ] .

Comment: This seems to work for me... What do you get...?

Comment: No need for a:link... just use 'a'. If you want a certain link to look a certain way just use a class. 

a {} will override anything unless you specify a class

.className {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
.tag18 {font-size:18px;}
```

It is best to not repeat CSS directives, let them cascade. Meaning, if .tag18 is going to be a certain family font and size, just set it within .tag18 and do your hovers with text-decoration, color, etc

Comment: Btw, try not to repeat CSS lines. Meaning, if .tag18 is going to be a certain family font and size, just set it within .tag18 and do your hovers with text-decoration, color, etc

Comment: I have a:link etc... defined also.

Comment: @st4ck0v3rfl0w - well said. Generally it is best to edit your answer rather than comment on it. I took the liberty on your behalf.

Comment: @rrrfusco: :link etc. will inherit properties of the normal state, no need to repeat. So as suggested, just assign font size and family to the normal state, and derived state (pseudoclasses) will inherit theses. The pseudoclasses are there just to have special visuals for when they are triggered.

Comment: @st4ck,
I re-phrased my question at the end.

Comment: I gave you the green checkmark, though your response didn't answer the question completely. See if you agree with my answer at the end of my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

The :link and :visited pseudo-classes must be defined before you define the :hover and :active

http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Just move your style declarations around and you'll be good

Comment: I re-phrased my question at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried testing it with Firebug?

http://getfirebug.com/

Once installed, you can inspect the element, and it will show you the CSS selectors that apply to it, including which ones override parent declarations.  I've found it helps **A LOT**.